# Detect the EventClass Audit Login/Logout in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler, audit-logging

I need to monitor an application when users log on and logoff in SQL SERVER, as sometimes the application logs unexpectedly, and I need to know because I audited the login and logout.
When I use SQL Server Profiler, EventClass column appear "Audit Login" and "Audit Logout". Is there any way to get those SQL Server Profiler events in C #?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: which version of sql server?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2005, but later will be migrating to SQL SERVER 2012. So I think it should work for any version of SQL SERVER.

Comment: The reason i asked is because sql 2008 introduced extended events which are much more performant than profiler or server side traces.   It may be worthwhile to rewrite this to use extended events when you get to sql 2012.

Comment: It seems to me a good point, however, is there a way obtain the information without having to save / read information in a file. trc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a server side trace that captures the events and columns of interest.  You can create it it profiler and save it as a create script.

Your c# program can query the trace using the fn_trace_gettable() system function.

You'll want to pay careful attention to the setup of the rollover files in the trace definition.  Filling up a disk drive isn't usually a good thing.